# Add Boundary Condition for Goal Seek

Tags: excel, vba, iteration

I am trying to create an automated Goal Seek script for a interlinked cells and workbook. However, perhaps due to the complexity and number of interlinks, somehow under a certain condition the Goal Seek function converges at a very high or low x-value.

Is there a way to improve its accuracy by setting some kind of boundary (a < x < b) similar to that in Solver. The reason I don't want to add solver in VBA is that because some of the other users may not be activating their Solver add-ins.

> This is what the Goal Seek value gives me for an initial guess of x =
>   0.5h = 500 [image]
>
> This is what the X-value should be, with a random guess of x = 100
>   [image]

Another alternative that I could think about is to create some sort of manual iteration (e.g. Bisection method) Sub Routine, but again, the equations are pretty complex so this may not be ideal.

What I am doing at the moment is that to preset an initial value for the x if y (another parameter) is negative or positive. I reckon this has eliminated most of the invalid result, but it still gives an error on one or two occasion. Appreciate your input. Thanks.

```
Sub Guess()
' ------------- For Guessing Initial X-Value -----------

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer


For i = 4 To 11
    For j = 18 To 25

    If Worksheets("Crack Width").Range("I" & j) < 0 Then
        '------------------------Pre-guess X_value to be 0.5X_bal if N<0-------------
        Worksheets("Calcs").Range("B" & i) = Worksheets("Calcs").Range("C" & i).Value * 0.5
        If Worksheets("Calcs").Range("B" & i) = 0 Then Worksheets("Calcs").Range("B" & i).ClearContent
        i = i + 1

    ElseIf Worksheets("Crack Width").Range("I" & j) >= 0 Then
        '------------------------Pre-guess X_value to be 0.5h if N>0-------------
        Worksheets("Calcs").Range("B" & i) = Worksheets("Calcs").Range("E" & i).Value * 0.5
        If Worksheets("Calcs").Range("B" & i) = 0 Then Worksheets("Calcs").Range("B" & i).ClearContents
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Might need more details of your set up. It may not have any bearing on it, but in options, calculation what is the maximum change setting?

Comment: @SJR Max.Change is default 0.0001.

To simplify the matter, let's just say there could be more than one x-value that can satisfy the goal seek function. In my case, x should never be more than h. However, under certain circumstances the goal seek returns a value of x that is much higher than h or less than 0.

The Pre-guess value I written in my code is based on my observation that if I expect x_trial > x_bal (when N>0; N is another defined parameter), then an initial guess off 0.5h will converge just fine. But apparently not always.

Comment: Could try playing around with it. https://superuser.com/questions/688691/why-is-that-sometimes-the-excel-goal-seek-doesnt-stop-exactly-at-zero/688991 Pity you can't use solver.

Comment: @SJR Is there a code to enable Solver Add-ins upon running a sub routine?